# How to go back to the previously selected card in card layout?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, cardlayout

This is how I shift my cards.

```
CardLayout card = (CardLayout) mainPanel.getLayout();
            card.show(mainPanel, "selectionPanel");
```

Once I am in the new card, I need to go back to the previously selected card from the back button. `card.previous()` do not work because the cards are not accessed in the same order.  How can I do this?

Comment: before you shift save the selected card in a variable

Comment: Thank you CodeCat . I'll try this soon .